# What's the most efficient way to score up?

Tags: a-for-the-awesome

I'm pretty confused about this game (I'm playing it on Steam, Oculus version, if that's of any importance): what's the best way to get points ?  Should I activate as many structures as I can ?  Or should I rather try to stick as long as possible to their surface (which makes a little sound, like an increasing counter) ?

Is it possible to display the score while falling ?  That would make it a lot clearer...

Comment: The score is displayed on screen while playing the game, maybe because of the Oculus you are not able to see it ?

Comment: Mhmmmm, yeah that's most probably it.  But there aren't many options about the display, in Oculus mode...  Damn.

Comment: You should try without Oculus to see how the HUD shows up and figure it precisely. But i don't know much about scoring though x)

Comment: @Edeph The HUD shows your hugs and kisses, but total score is not displayed until you finish a level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume this question is referring to [*For the Awesome*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/15560/AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA_for_the_Awesome/), the pseudo-sequel to [*A Reckless Disregard for Gravity*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/15520/AaAaAA__A_Reckless_Disregard_for_Gravity/), as the latter does not support Oculus Rift.

After analyzing gameplay from [artistcaleb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKcq7wVoiK0) and [Anti-Social Games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9a_Qbh5tc4), I've determined points are calculated as follows:

- Structures Kissed (Flying close to an object): 1,000 points each
- Hugs ([Repeatedly given while close to objects](https://youtu.be/xKcq7wVoiK0?t=109)): 100 points each
- Spectators Engaged ([Gesturing at spectators](https://youtu.be/t9a_Qbh5tc4?t=219)): 3,000 points per group<sup>1</sup>
- Plates Hit

  - Yellow plate: 250 points
  - Dark Yellow plate: 500 points
  - Orange plate: 750 points
  - Red plate: 1,000 points
  - Dark red: 2,000 points
- Stunts Hit

  - Threading the Needle ([Hug 4 structures at once](https://youtu.be/t9a_Qbh5tc4?t=462)): 5,500 points
  - Birdstrike ([hitting a bird](https://youtu.be/3rmPPZsNz8Q?t=956)): 5,000 points
- Graffiti Sprayed: Unknown. Could not find footage.
- Landing

  - Normal Landing: 0 points
  - Landing in Orange: 4,000 points
  - Landing in Red: 8,000 points
- Broken Bones

  - No Broken Bones: 1,000 points
  - All Bones Broken: 100% penalty, reduce score to 0

<sup>1</sup> Requires unlocking unlocking the Flip-It Glove. Each group counts as 5 spectators on the results screen, meaning you get 600 points per spectator.